# Writing test case in multiple module in single project does not build when done gradle build

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, junit5, gradlew

I have a project which consists of multiple modules (4 to be exact). Below is an example:

module A -> consists of main Application class with config. Similarly 
            module A also consists of multiple configuration classes.

module B -> consists of a ton of services.

module C -> consists of all the shared modules which can be used inter modules.

module D -> consists of the tasks that i'm currently working in.

Now since I'm writing unit test cases for the tasks in module D, it runs when I run individually run the tests or in that particular package.

But problem occurs when I run ./gradlew clean build

It says cannot find symbol in classes that are not in module D but they are in other modules like of C and B.

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({DModule.class, BModule.class})
public class DModuleTest {

    @Mock
    private DModule dModule;

    private DModuleService dModuleService;

    @Before
    public void setUp(){
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        dModuleService = PowerMockito.spy(new dModuleService());
    }

    @Test
    public void someMethod() {
       Mockito.when(dModuleService.someThing(Matchers.any()))
            .thenReturn(anyObject());
    }
}
```

Here, when building the project, it gives me error in BModule.class

I tried to add @ComponentScan, @SpringBootTest, @SpringBootApplication in that file but unable to build.

Comment: What does this have to do with `junit5`?

Comment: Please provide a _Minimum, Complete, and Verifiable Example_: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve